# Как ячейки таблицы заставить съезжать на другую строку при малых разрешениях?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть сетка с картинками в 4 столбиках отцентрированных по вертикали и горизонтали. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы на разрешениях `xs <576px` они по бутстраповси съезжали по 2 в строчку и не появлялся горизонтальный скролл, причем сохранить текущую кроссбраузерность? [Фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/9jjcn6fd/)

```css
.centered > .row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.centered > .row > div {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container centered">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x81">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x33">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x19">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x72">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x72">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x81">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x33">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x19">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С `display: table;` и  `display: table-cell;` это сделать не получиться!

Попробуйте использовать `display: flex;` + разметка для сетки `col-xs-6 col-sm-3` (50% - по 2-е на мобильных девайсах, по 4 - 25% уже на планшетах).

```css
.centered > .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.centered > .row > div {
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container centered">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x81">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x33">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x19">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x72">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x72">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x81">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x33">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x19">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант с псевдоэлементом и известной высотой div:

```css
.centered > .row > div {
   text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.centered > .row > div:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  
}

.centered > .row > div img {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container centered">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x81">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x33">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x19">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x72">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/80x72">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/70x81">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x33">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x19">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо. очень жаль только, что изначальная кроссбраузерность при это теряется.. а как-либо переопределить  блоки (сделать не табличными) на малых разрешениях нельзя?
ведь как-то же верстальщики должны были справляться с подобной задачей до изобретения `flex`. Спрашиваю, как у одной из самой уважаемой и опытной форумчанки!

Comment: @Вася, видимо до флекс и задачи такой не стояло (особенно когда верстали таблицами, об адаптивности и речи не было)! Есть еще такой вариант, но там нужно задавать высоту div https://jsbin.com/foceha/edit?html,css,output

Comment: спасибо, попробуем!